# Deactivate noise-cancelling of Logitech C270

Tags: linux, webcam, noise-cancelling

For a little project of mine, I would like to leverage an old Logitech C270 to record sound.

Unfortunately the built-in microphone [features noise-cancelling](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023462093-Logitech-HD-Webcam-C270-Technical-Specifications), which renders it pretty useless for my purpose.

Is there a way to deactivate this in software? Where would I start looking for such an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Logitech support and they told me this feature was implemented in hardware, therefore can not be disabled.